# using vba to connect to MariaDB connection problem

Tags: vba, mariadb, adodb

I can't get this connection to work, error message "data source not found and no default driver specified" but I have the driver downloaded.

Any ideas?

```
Sub ConnectToMariaDB()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim connectionString As String
    
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    
    ' Set the connection string
    conn.connectionString = "DRIVER={MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver};" _
        & "SERVER=10.0.0.10;" _
        & "DATABASE=Customers;" _
        & "USER=prod1;" _
        & "PASSWORD=12345;"
    
    ' Open the connection
    conn.Open
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Downloading is not enough. You also have to install the driver

Comment: Make sure if you're using 32-bit Office you downloaded the 32-bit driver, and likewise if you're using 64-bit office you need the 64-bit driver.